# How to declare an array with X elements in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there any way to declare and reserve a space for a big array without using `table.insert`?
Something like in Python:

```
a = [0]*10000
```

or in C:

```
malloc(10000*sizeof(int))
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are trying to map concepts from other environments to Lua and they aren't all that useful in Lua: "array", "declare", "reserve space"; Even "X elements" is more accurate as "X key-value pairs." Ergo, @lhf's questions.

Comment: I think you are mistaking as to what python code does. The multiplication does not reserve space. Try `[] == []*10000` , or `sys.getsizeof([]*10000`.)

Comment: `[0] * 10000` creates a list with 10000 elements, all zero, `[] * 10000` is just an empty list.

Comment: Perhaps trying to achieve some type of optimization by pre-creating the array with the assumption that access to entries 1->10000 would now be very fast? If so, interesting, but not sure it would make a difference. If this is your aim, would love to see the results after implementing ihf's suggestion

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the python snippet, it should be `[0]*1000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua tables are dynamic: they grow as needed. There is no need (and no way) to declare a large array. Just create it with `a={}` and fill it as needed.

If you must create a large array, just fill it with some value:

```
a={}
for i=1,10000 do
  a[i]=true
end
```

In any case, this is not really a job for `table.insert`.